# How to replace a row in QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: qt, model-view

In QAbstractItemModel, some functions, such as beginInsertRows, beginRemoveRows, can be used to insert and remove rows. But how to implement replacing a row item by another one?

Comment: Seems like a replacement is just a removal followed by an insertion.

Comment: This way works, but I think there should be a better way.

Comment: also, remove+insert will certainly lose the selection and the expanded state (for a tree)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you need to notify subcribed views about data changing (one row replaced by new, for views it means that data has been changed) for the specified model index:

```
// let's the row is index that we want to invalidate
QVector<int> roles;
roles << Qt::DisplayRole;
emit dataChanged(index(row, 0), index(row, columnCount()-1), roles);
```

Comment: I tried, but sometimes it doesn't work right. Currently I emit `layoutChanged()` signal. It works but I am wondering if this is expensive.

Comment: I have a parent node. I change it to another parent node with different children. And then emit the `dataChanged` signal with the first index as the parent and the last index as the last child of the parent. I also try setting the first and last index same as the parent. Both doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: your situation can be solved with Chris's suggestion, view must known that you change tree structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a lot of data, you should do something like this:

```
beginResetModel();
// change data
endResetModel();
```

If you change just one row, emitting dataChanged() should do the trick.